# One DIV section is hidden completely

Tags: jquery, html, css

I added a image hover effect using jquery : http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/HmTrw/

my site : http://windows7themer.com

After that I am unable to see the details as you see in this image.

[image: Unable to see the details]

Now after i added the script, the div section is like this :

[image]

The title, category , author and number of pageviews are hidden by the image. Though i can see them in the source code of the page.

Can someone help me in displaying those details under div class : mosaic-overlay

Comment: Huh?  What's the problem here?  How does that jsFiddle demo relate to this question?

Comment: I added that image effect in my site. You can see that in second image. When i hover the image, the image will zoom just like in google images.

Comment: Oh, ok.  You didn't have the link to your site in the question originally, so I was confused.

Comment: ya sorry for that.. Edited the question now

Comment: If you can create an example jsfiddle that duplicates your problem it would help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `opacity: 0` in several different places on elements of class `mosaic-overlay`.  Why?  If you take that away, it works fine.

Comment: Oh ya.. It's working.. But its added by jquery on hovering images.. However default value is <code>opacity: 0</code> which i must delete now..